# Eliminating out-of-range ASCII characters from string

Tags: javascript, string, replace, ascii

Using JavaScript, I want to reduce a string to include characters within ASCII 65-90 only (uppercase letters from A-Z).

My function starts with turning the string into full uppercase. Spaces are eliminated next and finally, letters are converted to ASCII decimals.

I want letters A-Z only (ASCII 65-90), nothing else. What if the string, however, does contain one or more non-desired characters? Is there a way to eliminate all instances of characters `<` ASCII 65 and `>` ASCII 90 from a string?

Comment: You should use "Regular Expressions". https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions (/^[A-Z]/g) likely the pattern you need

Comment: Use `.replace(/[^A-Z]/g, "")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a simple reduce call:

```js
const input = "asddgAeBcc6$$Cz>>,,";
const output = Array.prototype.reduce.call(input, (res, c) => res + ((c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') ? c: ""), "");

console.log({ input, output })
```